# ¿ Como hacer una clase que se comunique con otra clase en Java?

Tags: java

Hola muy buenas ¿ que tal ?

Soy novato todavia en programación con Java y estoy comenzando a aprender ya ciertas cosas un poco más avanzadas , como por ejemplos programación orientada a objetos.

Bueno,  estoy queriendo programar un ejercicio donde creo una "casa inteligente" que es manejada con un mando a distancia. Como ejemplo os voy a poner aqui una clase básica que tengo ya creada de una lampara.

Lo que quisiera hacer es una clase "mando a distancia" al estilo del metodo interruptor ,  para que con esta clase pueda encender y apagar , no solo la lampara sino cualquier otra clase que pueda crear de aparatos electricos.

Con el metodo interruptor que tengo dentro de la clase Lampara ya puedo "encender" y "apagar" la lampara, pero mi idea es utilizar otra clase independiente que apague y encienda la lampara o cualquier otro aparato , al estilo de lo que hace la clase interruptor dentro de la clase Lampara pero independientemente. Para poder reutilizar esta clase con otros aparatos dentro de la casa . Al estilo de un mando a distancia.  He creado otra clase MandoDistancia haciendo un intento de crear lo mismo del interruptor pero no funciona así. ¿ Que debo de hacer ? Debo de decir que aún no he dado materia sobre Herencia ni Poliformismo. Agradezco vuestra ayuda de antemano. Saludos.

Esto es un ejemplo básico de lo que estoy haciendo :

```
public class Lampara {
    
    private boolean estado;
           
        public Lampara (){
    }
                 
    public void interruptor() {
        estado = ! estado; // metodo que asigna el valor contrario
    }
        
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = estado ? " encendida":" apagada";
        return "La lampara está" + s ;
    } 
}

public class MandoDistancia {

    private boolean estado = true;

    public boolean estadoMando() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void interruptor() {
        estado = !estado; // asigna el valor contrario
    }
}


public class Habitacion {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Bombilla bombilla = new Bombilla();
        
        MandoDistancia mandodistancia = new MandoDistancia();
        
        System.out.println(bombilla);
        
        bombilla.interruptor();
              
        System.out.println(bombilla);
        
        mandodistancia.interruptor();
        
        System.out.println(bombilla);               
        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de tu ejercicio, lo que deberías hacer, es que a tus dispositivos de la habitación **cuenten con el método cambiar estado** y el _control maneje todos los estados posibles_, ya que en teoría es como un mando universal. Además el mando debe tener un objeto de cada aparato inteligente para poder llamar al método cambiar estado.

Comment: Exacto @DarkFrost. Esto era lo que queria hacer. Desde la clase mando  cambiar el estado de los demas aparatos. La cuestión aqui era que aún no sabía que desde una clase podia crear un objeto de cada aparato y poder llamar al metodo cambiar estado. Gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la clase `MandoDistancia` interactúe con la bombilla deberías de pasarle al "mando" alguna "bombilla".

Sin complicarte mucho la vida, podrías hacer simplemente un método dentro de la clase `MandoDistancia` que reciba como argumento una `Lampara`, de este modo el mando podrá de alguna forma invocar al método de la lámpara que realiza todas las acciones necesarias para que la lámpara se apague (cambie de estado).

Tu clase `MandoDistancia` se vería así:

```
public class MandoDistancia {
    private boolean estado = true;

    public boolean estadoMando() {
        return estado;
    }
    
    public void interruptor( Lampara l ) {
        l.interruptor();
    }
    
}
```

Esta no es (ni de lejos) la mejor forma de hacer lo que pretendes, ya que en el momento que añadas más objetos con los que pueda interactuar el mando vas a empezar escribir código redundante, es decir, empezarías a **sobrecargar** el método `interruptor()` de la clase `MandoDistancia` por cada nuevo objeto que añadieras (a objeto me refiero a cualquier elemento con el que pudiera interactuar el mando), como por ejemplo una televisón.

Para solucionar este problema puedes crear una clase "genérica" para los dispositivos con los que puede interactuar el mando, como por ejemplo la clase:

```
public class Dispositivo {
    public abstract void interruptor();
}
```

Quizá sería mejor usar interfaces, pero creo que es demasiado para una pregunta tan específica.

Entonces tu clase `Lampara` extendería de la clase `Dispositivo`:

```
public class Lampara extends Dispositivo {
      
    ....
    
    @Override         
    public void interruptor() {
        estado = ! estado; // metodo que asigna el valor contrario
    }

    ....
}
```

De este modo, el mando en vez de recibir algo de tipo `Lampara` en su método `interruptor()`, recibe algo como: "una instancia de un dispositivo que sé que implementa su propia lógica de interruptor", es decir:

```
public class MandoDistancia {

    ....
    
    public void interruptor( Dispositivo dis ) {
        dis.interruptor() // asigna el valor contrario
    }
    
    ....
}
```

Quizá me he extendido de más para lo específica que era tu pregunta, pero al menos que te sirva de guía o como punto de partida para experimentar con esta parte de Java.

Comment: Ante todo gracias por tu respuesta. En principio solucioné el ejercicio con la primera solución, es decir creando un método dentro de la clase MandoDistancia que recibe como argumento Lampara. Ya sé que no es lo más adecuado , pero como he comentado, este mundo es nuevo para mi y aún no sabía que podía crear un metodo que recibiera un objeto de argumento. :) Como bien dices el problema está que en cuanto quiera manejar varios aparatos voy a tener que crear tantos metodos como aparatos tenga y está claro que resulta redundante

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es muy genérica y se puede resolver de muchas maneras.
Los objetos se comunican o interactúan entre ellos a través de sus métodos.

Lo que tenes que resolver es como **MandoDistancia** accede al método para encender/apagar la **Lampara**.
Por ejemplo: creá un método en **MandoDistancia** que reciba un objeto **Lampara** y cambie su estado.

```
public void cambiarLampara(Lampara l){    
    l.interruptor();
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

igualmente sería bueno que aprendas herencia para resolver este problema, saludos.

Comment: No sabia que desde una clase también podia interactuar con objetos accediendo a sus métodos, hoy aqui he aprendido una cosa nueva y ahora lo entiendo mejor. Está claro que para programar este tipo de casos, la herencia es lo mejor. Sin duda lo próximo que haré será aprender herencia. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.